# How to compute the outer product of two matrices in numpy?

Tags: numpy

I have two matrices A and B of size NxK and MxK respectively. I wish to compute a tensor C of size NxMxK such that C(i,j,k) = A(i,k)*B(j,k).

How can I implement this efficiently in numpy?
All the dimensions are large, and hence, looping isn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a literal translation of the iterators from the loopy version as string notation with `np.einsum`, we would have the solution -

```
np.einsum('ik,jk->ijk',A,B)
```

Sample run -

```
In [2]: N,K,M = 3,4,5

In [3]: A = np.random.rand(N,K)

In [4]: B = np.random.rand(M,K)

In [5]: np.einsum('ik,jk->ijk',A,B).shape
Out[5]: (3, 5, 4)

In [6]: (N,M,K)
Out[6]: (3, 5, 4)
```

Comment: Seriously!! Thanks a trillion. Don't you mean 'ik,jk -> ijk'?

Comment: Oh, it's the same. Thanks :)

Comment: @user2808118 You were right, that wasn't a direct translation. Thanks, edited.